# Regular expressions (denominator of a fraction)

Tags: java, regex

Soo i think i already solved it, what i did:

```
String pattern = "(<=|>=)\\s{0,2}((+]\\s{0,2})?(\\d+\\s{0,2}[/]\\s{0,2}(\\d{2,}|[1-9])\\s{0,2}|\\d+[.]\\d{1,2}|\\d+))\\s{0,2}";
```

The pattern had something wrong, i have corrected it above and now it works :)

I have an inequation that may containing >= or <=, some white spaces and a number. That number might be an integer, a decimal number with 2 decimal places or a fraction and I want to retrieve the number on the 2nd member of the inequation with the "Matcher". Example:

```
4x1 + 6x2 <= 40/3
```

I've tried to construct such a pattern and I was able to find it. But then I've remembered that a fraction cannot be divided by zero so I want to check that aswell. For that I have used the following code:

```
String inequation = "4x1 + 6x2 <= 40/3";
String pattern = "(<=|>=)\\s{0,2}((+]\\s{0,2})?(\\d+\\s{0,2}[/]\\s{0,2}(\\d{2,}|[1-9])\\s{0,2}\\d+|\\d+[.]\\d{1,2}|\\d+))\\s{0,2}";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher match = ptrn.matcher(inequation);
if(match.find()){
String fraction = match.group(2);
System.out.println(fraction);
} else {
System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

But it's not working as expected. If it has at least 2 digits on the denominator it returns correctly (e.g. 40/32). But if it only has 1 digit it only returns the integer part (e.g. 40).

Anyway to solve this?
Which expression should I use?

Comment: Can you show us your output?

Comment: In the example i gave the output is 40. 
As i said if i have on the 2nd member a fraction like this "40/32" it returns correctly (returns 40/32), but if the fraction on the 2nd member is something like this "40/3" the output comes with just the numerator (40).

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/) to build regular expressions. It shows you a nice diagram of your expression and you can test your inputs as well.

**Java implementation** (validates that the numerator is non-zero.):

```
    Matcher m  = Pattern.compile("[<>]=?\\s{0,2}([0-9]*(/[1-9][0-9]*)?)$").matcher("4x1 + 6x2 <= 40/3");
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

You need an '$' at the end of your expression, so that it tries to match the entire inequality.

Comment: Im using Java :( Doesnt show an option there for Java

Comment: You can use javascript. It's mostly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want the number after the inequality sign? Then do:

```
Matcher m  = Pattern.compile("[<>]=?\\s*(.+?)\\s*$").matcher(string);
String number = m.find() ? m.group(1) : null;
```